# Google sheet Error - Array arguments to SUMIFS are of different size

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using below formula to calculate SUM of column V when A column Year  matches to 2021 and A column month matches to January (1)

```
=SUMIFS('Trade Log'!V:V,YEAR('Trade Log'!A:A),"2021",MONTH('Trade Log'!A:A),"1")
```

But this giving me below error

```
Error
Array arguments to SUMIFS are of different size.
```

Unable to figure out the issue here. Any guidance please

[Sample Google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AAw0ie0RT5rY6hZ7RePDRDKUrikQBDX1YvQQaWWAG_Y/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: The error appears because the size of the range `YEAR('Trade Log'!A:A)` is one cell and it cannot match the size of the range `'Trade Log'!V:V`. To align the sizes of the ranges use the `ArrayFormula()` formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
=SUMPRODUCT(YEAR(A:A) = 2021, MONTH(A:A) = 1, V:V)
```

and see if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(SUMIFS('Trade Log'!V:V,
 YEAR('Trade Log'!A:A), "2021",
 MONTH('Trade Log'!A:A), "1"))
```